# What does "cooks crystal" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

> Jack Reaper: So he works here?
>   Sandy: Ya. It's bullshit though. He cooks crystal.

[image]

I saw this [conversation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mG6jvlQffFo) in the movie called Jack Reaper. What does "cooks crystal" mean? From the context it seemed like it means the work is of bad quality, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You've never watch *Breaking Bad*? Gosh, it's a rarity to find someone as untainted by such concepts. You probably think pot roast is only for dinner, or weed is taken care of with Roundup.

Comment: @BlessedGeek it's not rare :). You just need to know where to look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't seen the movie, but it sounds like she's talking about crystal meth, aka [methamphetamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methamphetamine). So, roughly:

> Jack: So he works here?
>
> Sandy: Yeah, but it's just a cover. He makes drugs.

EDIT: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0790724/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl) seems to agree.

> She tells Reacher that she pretty much did whatever Jeb told her to do. She said Jeb was supposed to be an employee at the same auto parts store (he hadn't come in to work that day), but she said he really made his money from crystal meth.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Drug Slang Dictionary](http://www.noslang.com/drugs/dictionary/c/):

> **cook** - Drug manufacturer
>
> **crystal** - Cocaine; amphetamine; methamphetamine; PCP

*He **manufactures** a popular **drug** that has a crystalline composition.*